# asynchronous Javascript/async: should return not interrupt function immediately?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, loopbackjs

Using `loopback` for a project.
The following function is one out of three tasks that get fired via the `async` library:

```
async.parallel([
      function(cb) {
        find_car(cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        find_parts(cb);
      },
      function(cb) {
        find_records(cb);
      }
], function(err, results) {
    //handle results
});


//inside find_car
Car.find({where: query}, function(err, cars) {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    return callback(err);
  }
  if (cars && cars.length > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
      var car = cars[i];
      car.owner(function(err, owner) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
          return callback(err, null); 
        }
        if (owner) {
          var msg = "A car with " + field + " " + value + " is already in the DB.";
          return callback(msg, null); // --> async FIRES EXCEPTION HERE
        }
          return callback(null, true);
      });
    }
  } else {
    return callback(null, true);
  }   
});
```

}

I do understand that due to the asynchronous nature of the `car.owner()` call, the iteration is already calling (and coming back in the callback) the second time by the time I call the `callback` the first time.

But what strikes me is that my code does

```
return callback(msg, null);
```

> "The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to
>   be returned to the function caller."
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

So I would expect that after my first call of callback, function execution should be **immediately interrupted** and the function `find_car` returning immediately, not allowing any further code execution.

Instead I get an exception:

```
/home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/context.js:78
      throw exception;
            ^
Error: Callback was already called.
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:43:36
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/common/models/car.js:279:15
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/relation-definition.js:1490:11
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1548:5
    at Object.forward (/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/proxy.js:79:23)
    at eval (eval at wrap (/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.7/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/proxy.js:197:20), <anonymous>:3:21)
    at /home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1479:9
    at done (/home/me/prj/gfh/src/loopback/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:19)
```

Comment: *"should return not interrupt function immediately?"* From the context that the return is in, yes, but that's not the case with your code. You're returning from a callback, which is very different. The loop has already finished running by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoke `callback` `cars.length` times, for you are invoking `car.owner` the same number of times and there are `cars.length` instances of the provided function.

Each one will invoke sooner or later `callback` and that results in an error.

It doesn't matter if you exit the specific instance using a `return` statement. The other instances are still running and allowed to invoke `callback` the same way.

The sole cases that work fine are the ones when `cars.length` is 0 or 1, for obvious reasons.